# Error when applying incremental learning in XGBoost for a classification setting (python)

Tags: python-3.x, classification, xgboost

**Python version: 3.5 // xgboost version: 0.7.post3**

Hi everyone,

I am trying to implement **incremental learning** using the **xgboost module** in python, where my **target variable is binary**. I think I am supposed to set the parameter **"process_type": "update"**. The thing is that I get an error that I am not able to solve. Here I put an example implementation of my code using the breast cancer dataset from sklearn so everyone can give it a try. Does anybody know how I can prevent the following error from happening?

```
from sklearn import datasets
import xgboost

X_all = datasets.load_breast_cancer().data
y_all = datasets.load_breast_cancer().target

X_first_half = X_all[0:280,:]
X_second_half = X_all[280:,:]
y_first_half = y_all[0:280]
y_second_half = y_all[280:]

model1 = xgboost \
    .train({'objective': 'binary:logistic'},
           dtrain=xgboost.DMatrix(X_first_half, y_first_half),
           xgb_model=None)

model2 = xgboost \
    .train({'objective': 'binary:logistic',
            'process_type': 'update',
            'update': 'refresh',
            'refresh_leaf': True},
           dtrain=xgboost.DMatrix(X_second_half, y_second_half),
           xgb_model=model1)
```

The error that I get is:

```
XGBoostError: b'[15:03:03] src/tree/updater_colmaker.cc:118:
Check failed: tree.param.num_nodes == tree.param.num_roots (19 vs. 1)
ColMaker: can only grow new tree\n\nStack trace returned 1 entries:\n[bt] (0)
```

Comment: Do you understand what 'process_type': 'update' is doing ?

Comment: I think I more or less understand what this argument is doing. Basically, I would like to update previous model fits by adding new data in batches. Do you know how to modify the previous code to achieve this? I have followed the same procedure as the following tutorial, which tries to achieve the same thing as me but in a regression setting instead of classification setting: https://gist.github.com/ylogx/53fef94cc61d6a3e9b3eb900482f41e0

Comment: the kwarg `update` should be changed to `updater`

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I think he is trying to achieve a sort of batch training, I mean to further train the model with new data points without adding more trees to the ensemble. In other words, update the current trees/leafs to the new data points.

From the docs:

> process_type, [default=’default’]
>
> A type of boosting process to run.
>     Choices: {‘default’, ‘update’}
>         ‘default’: the normal boosting process which creates new trees.
>         ‘update’: starts from an existing model and only updates its trees. In each boosting iteration, a tree from the initial model is taken, a specified sequence of updater plugins is run for that tree, and a modified tree is added to the new model. The new model would have either the same or smaller number of trees, depending on the number of boosting iteratons performed. Currently, the following built-in updater plugins could be meaningfully used with this process type: ‘refresh’, ‘prune’. With ‘update’, one cannot use updater plugins that create new trees.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it just copies the documentation for `process_type` without explaining how the code in the question could be improved

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question, but if anyone is still facing the same issue, try tweaking the `tree_method` parameter.

I got the same error message when I was incrementally training an old model. In my case, the old model was trained with parameter `{'tree_method': 'exact'}`, but I was however using `{'tree_method': 'hist'}` to update it. The problem was resolved after changing `tree_method` to `exact`.

Or, if you are able to update xgboost, simply updating to a version > 1.0 should also solve the problem. As the low-level `num_roots` parameter which is causing this error [was removed](https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/pull/5059/commits) in higher versions.

(Also remember to change the kwarg `update` to `updater` in the pasted code as @Fortunato mentioned in the comment.)